# ferris wheel animation (making things move in a circle) python

Tags: python, windows, animation, geometry

I am trying to make a ferris wheel animation (in practice for object oriented programming) but I am struggling to get the carriage around the wheel.

```
#ferris wheel(circle)
pygame.draw.circle(screen, blue, [250,250],150, 8)

#carriage
pygame.draw.polygon(screen, yellow, [[220+cx,385+cy],[280+cx,385+cy],[270+cx,400+cy],[230+cx,400+cy]],0)

def carriagemovement(top,bottom):

global cx
global cy
top = 0
bottom = 1
if bottom == 1:
    if cx == 0 or cx < 80:
        cx = cx + 4
        cy = cy - 1
        print(cx)
else:
    if bottom == 1:
        if cx == 80 or ( cx > 80 and cx < 148):
            cx = cx + 4
            cy = cy - 3
            print (cx)
    else:
        if bottom ==1:
            if cx == 148 or (cx > 148 and cx < 159):
                cx = cx + 0.5
                cy = cy - 3
                print (cx)
        else:
            top = 1
            bottom = 0
            if top == 1:
                if (cx == 159 and top == 1) or (cx < 159 and top == 1):
                    cx = cx - 0.5
                    cy = cy - 3
                    print (cx)
```

The carriagemovement() is the way I'm currently doing (but it goes off the circle due to if statements and when I fixed that (using top and bottom), it just stops short).

Is there a function or a method I'm not using that would make it easier? Is there another way?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be more intuitive to transform the problem from "x,y" Cartesian coordinates into "angle, distance" polar coordinates.  Then to move around the circle you need only increment the angle.  If you want to get x,y values out of it still, you can simply transform them using trigonometry (sine/cosine).

Comment: thanks that makes much more sense! But can you give me an example? I have not done polar co-ordinates yet